# I made a recursive function in javascript that filters out strings from an inputted array. Why does it go through the for loop 3 extra times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, conditional-statements

```js
function filter_list(l) {

  var count = l.length;
  console.log('the count is:', count);

  function loop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var type = (typeof l[i]);

      if (type == 'string') {
        l.splice(i, 1);
        console.log('the list is', l);
        filter_list(l);
      } else {
        console.log('this item is', l[i], 'the list is', l);
      }
    }
  }

  loop()
}

filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'c', 'd']);
```

Essentially, it does get the job done, however for the final for loop, I am not sure why it runs through it 3 extra times? Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: You modify the array with `splice`, but the `count` stays the same.

Comment: if you're splicing elements off your array, you're better to traverse the list in reverse, that way you arent try to access an element at an index that doesnt exist, as for why its running a number of times.. when you call `filter_list(l)` inside your if statement, you're starting the loop all over again, best to either traverse in reverse as above, or to put a `break` statement after you call `filter_list(l)` which will prevent the for loop from continuing

Comment: Why are you using both iteration and recursion at the same time? Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: @haxxxton Ahh, I get it. The recursion was his way to solve the problem of deleting while he traverses in forward order.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the comments guys! Very enlightening. As was stated below, I totally forget filter was a thing hahaha. Although, I find it equally as rewarding to realize why certain errors such as this one occur.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but if all you need to do is filter strings out of an array, you could more easily do this with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
[1, 2, 'a', 'c', 'd'].filter(function(i) { return typeof i !== 'string' });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fodvowbn/)

Or, if you want to keep it as a standalone function:

```
function filter_list(array) {
  return array.filter(function(i) { return typeof i !== 'string' });
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, in regards to solving the original problem. Thank you very much!